# Are tags with 20+ % unsung answers healthy?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, tag-score, zero-score-badges

I recycled an old query for [Top tags with a high proportion of zero-vote accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375861/top-tags-with-a-high-proportion-of-zero-vote-accepted-answers): quite a bit are around 20 % in StackOverflow. (Someone should check other sites.)

The top tag there has just one frequent answerer with 500 answers and 300 total score, but others often have the same pattern with a handful users, so it's not about individuals I think. Some are just [unpopular tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167967/unpopular-tags-and-accepted-answers) but not all of them.

Is this a problem? The first affected things which come to my mind are:

- motivation of the users in the tag (chance that they disappear);
- relative motivation of the users (chance they move to more rewarding tags);
- meaningfulness of tag score requirements;
- meaningfulness of other score requirements for review privileges etc.

Comment: Sometimes is because there's actually only one of such experts on the topic. Also Pareto principle.